# Find the number of all ordered pairs $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ of $a+b+c+d+e+f=11,a+b\le c+d\le e+f$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of all ordered pairs $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ of nonnegative integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, and $f$ that satisfy the following equation.
$$a+b+c+d+e+f=11$$
$$a+b\le c+d\le e+f$$

Using Mathematica, 924 are obtained. How do you generally approach solutions? Here is my code:

{a, b, c, d, e, f} /.
Solve[0 <= {a, b, c, d, e, f} && a + b + c + d + e + f == 11 &&
a + b <= c + d <= e + f, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, Integers] // Length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

say
$x=a+ b$ .............(i)
$y=c+ d$...............(ii)
$z=e+ f$...............(iii)
so we have $x+y+z=11$ where  $x\le y\le z$
now the triples $(x, y, z)$ are under the restriction $x\le y\le z$
$(0,0,11)$,
$(0,1,10),(0,2,9),(0,3,8),(0,4,7),(0,5,6),$
$(1,1,9),(1,2,8),(1,3,7),(1,4,6),(1,5,5),$
$(2,2,7),(2,3,6),(2,4,5),$
$(3,3,5),(3,4,4)$

$x,y,z$ all are sum of two non negative numbers.
number of solutions to equation (i) is ${(x+2-1)\choose(2-1)}$ =$(x+1)$
similarly number of solution to equation (ii) and (iii) is (y+1) and (z+1) respectively.
The question asks for the number of ordered pairs$(a, b, c, d, e, f)$
here $a,b$ come from the solutions of the equation (i),there are $x+1$ many such $(a, b)$
same for $c,d$ and $e,f$
let there are $3$ boxes the $1st$ one can be filled up in ${(x+1)\choose1}$ =$x+1$ ways.(the $1st$ box can take elements from those $(x+1)$ pairs only, as $x\le y\le z$, same for $2nd$ and $3rd$ box)
$2nd$ one in $(y+1)$ ways and
$3rd$ one in$(z+1)$ ways.
So total number of ways we can fill up those three boxes is $(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)$
For each triple $(x, y, z)$ in the above list we can write it as $((a, b),(b, c),(e, f))$ and the total number of such pair is $(x+1)(y+1)(z+1).$
now calculate $(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)$ for each triple in the list given and add them up. The answer will be $924$.
For the first triple $(0,0,11)$ it is $1\times1\times12=12$
for the second triple $(0,1,10)$ it is $1\times2\times11=22$
this way calculate $(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)$ for each triple and sum them.
This way I have done it and got $924$.